# Python 3.4 invalid syntax despite fallback value set?

Tags: python-3.x

Just writing up my first class which is basically an Ohms law calculator in the **init** method i have set some defult fallback values as i understand but they don't seem to be working heres my code.

```
__author__ = 'rvncpn'
```

class ohms:

```
def __init__(self, volts=0, amps=0, ohms=0):
    self.v = volts
    self.i = amps
    self.r = ohms
    self.w = []


def sorter(self):

    if self.v > 0:
        self.w.append('volts')
    if self.i > 0:
        self.w.append('amps')
    if self.r > 0:
        self.w.append('ohms')

def listCheck(self):

    if 'volts' in self.w and 'amps' in self.w and 'ohms' in self.w:
            print('you must leave one of the perimeter empty')
    elif 'volts' in self.w and 'amps' in self.w:
        print('resistance =', self.v / self.i)
    elif 'volts' in self.w and 'ohms' in self.w:
        print('amps =', self.i / self.i)
    elif 'amps' in self.w and 'ohms' in self.w:
        print('volts=', self.i * self.r)
    else:
        pass
```

c1 = ohms(,3,0)

print(c1.sorter(), c1.listCheck())

** It keep's throwing up this error which i know is a syntax error but if i move the blank empty around it works ie (33,33,) **

```
 File "xxxxxxxxxxxx", line 37
c1 = ohms(,9,0)
          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Why do you believe that a default argument value will protect you from invalid syntax?

Comment: i assumed that if the argument is left blank it would default back to 0?